# How to Limit the User to stop submit form Untill the time on string expired in php?

Tags: php, string, forms, timer, submit

How do i limit the user to submit the form once in 24 hour window in php.
No Logins required for submit the form. Is there any way to set the timer on a specific string ? 
Any help appreciate .?

EDIT:

I built a simple submit form for URL using POST method and for validation and checks i used simple "empty" & "preg_match" variables which works fine.

```
URL Submit.php
<form action="xyz.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="website">

xyz.php

if (empty($_POST["website"])) { ........
```

Now I want the user to submit the URL form once in 24 hour. For that, How to set the timer on a string or how to force the user to submit same url until your time expired .? This should be done in php not in Javascript. Any Idea which function or variable and how to use ?

Comment: Try using a session or a cookie.

Comment: First of all, use proper tags and put some code that you have. What you tried? what you tried but failed? We can't read your mind.

Comment: @Mikey sessions and cookies will not work because if user remove history, cookies and sessions from their browser or change ip address then they will submit another form.